# How do i send a file from a form

Tags: php, html

i have created a form where if the user enters in their details and clicks submit an email is sent to the defined email address, my question is how do i allow the user to add a file to the form and then send to the defined email address:

HTML:

```
<form>
```

Name

```
            <p>
                <input class = 'input-text' type = 'text' name = 'Number' placeholder = 'Number' required/>
                <label>Number</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input class = 'input-text' type = 'email' name = 'Email' placeholder = 'Email' required/>
                <label>Email</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input class = 'input-text' type = 'text' name = 'Company' placeholder = 'Company' required/>
                <label>Company</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input class = 'upload' type = 'file' name = 'File' placeholder = 'Please upload your business plan'>
                <label>Upload a business plan </label>
            </p>
            <textarea type = 'text' placeholder = 'Any Comments?'></textarea>
            <br />
            <button class = 'send' value = 'submit' type = 'submit'>Send</button>
            <button class = 'reset' value = 'reset' type = 'reset'>Reset</button>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];


$to = "jackbryan49@msn.com";
$subject = "ADSML Contact Form";
$body = "This is an email from the ADMSL website, Please do not reply to this email. \n\n From:  $name \n Contact Number:  $number \n Contact Email:  $email \n Company Name:  $company \n User Comments:  $comments";

mail ($to, $subject, $body);
header( 'Location: http://paulbryanpotatoes.com/ADMSL/Contact.html' ) ;
```

?>

Comment: maybe you can use [this tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html) to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sending attachments with PHP's `mail()` function is a pain and not worth the bother. I would use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) instead. Hopefully the example on the home page should be sufficient to get you up and running with it.

Answer (score 0):

To handle files in PHP you should use `$_FILE`

[Offical API-Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

If you want to send a File by E-Mail, you should encrypt the bytestream of the file in Base64 and add it to the E-Mail as attachment.